# combining strings from following ID with strings in current ID

Tags: r

I have dataframe as below. I want to `paste0` each pair of `current` which are in subsequent `state` number.

```
df
state   current
  1       A1
  1       B1
  2       A2
  2       A3
  3       B2
  3       C1
```

I want all possible twin combination of `current` column with only the next `state`

```
resultdf:

combinations
A1A2
A1A3
B1A2
B1A3
A2B2
A2C1
A3B2
A3C1
```

how can I do it in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.table` version with a join of `state` to `state + 1`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dat[, statep1 := state + 1]
dat[dat, on="state==statep1", nomatch=0L, paste0(i.current, current)]
#[1] "A1A2" "A1A3" "B1A2" "B1A3" "A2B2" "A2C1" "A3B2" "A3C1"
```

Similar logic in base R:

```
dat$statep1 <- dat$state + 1
with(merge(dat, dat, by.x="state", by.y="statep1"), paste0(current.y, current.x) )
#[1] "A1A2" "B1A2" "A1A3" "B1A3" "A2B2" "A3B2" "A2C1" "A3C1"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using base R

```
#Create a comma separated string for each `state`
df1 <- aggregate(current~state, df, toString)

#Function to create combination of strings
get_rolling_paste <- function(x, y) {
    df2 <- expand.grid(trimws(strsplit(x, ",")[[1]]), trimws(strsplit(y, ",")[[1]]))
    paste0(df2$Var1, df2$Var2)
}

#apply the function to every row and it's previous row
x <- c(sapply(2:nrow(df1), function(x) 
       get_rolling_paste(df1$current[x-1], df1$current[x])))
x
#[1] "A1A2" "B1A2" "A1A3" "B1A3" "A2B2" "A3B2" "A2C1" "A3C1"
```

You can convert it to a dataframe if you want

```
resultdf <- data.frame(combinations = x)

#  combinations
#1         A1A2
#2         B1A2
#3         A1A3
#4         B1A3
#5         A2B2
#6         A3B2
#7         A2C1
#8         A3C1
```

FYI, `df1` is

```
#  state current
#1     1  A1, B1
#2     2  A2, A3
#3     3  B2, C1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple way using `for` loop -

```
result <- NULL
for(r in seq_len(nrow(df)-2)) {
  n <- ifelse(rep(r %% 2 > 0, 2), 2:3, 1:2)
  result <- c(result, paste0(df$current[r], df$current[r+n]))
}

result
[1] "A1A2" "A1A3" "B1A2" "B1A3" "A2B2" "A2C1" "A3B2" "A3C1"
```

Here's another way using `?outer()` -

```
result <- NULL
for(r in seq(1, nrow(df)-2, 2)) {
  result <- c(result, 
              c(outer(df$current[r:(r+1)], df$current[(r+2):(r+3)], FUN = paste0))
            )
}

result
[1] "A1A2" "B1A2" "A1A3" "B1A3" "A2B2" "A3B2" "A2C1" "A3C1"
```

Growing `result` vector like that is bad practice but shouldn't matter unless you have high number of rows.